# How to plot a region in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, regions

I want to plot the following region in Mathematica:

$\{(x,y)\in 10^{-5}\mathbb{Z}^2|~x^2+y^2<1\}.$

How should we write the code for that?

Comment: You really want to plot 20000 *separate* dots? What exactly is the point? Your screen does not have the resolution anyway.

Comment: Try RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 1, {x, -1.1, 1.1}, {y, -1.1, 1.1}]

Answer (score 1):

As @Szabolcs pointed out in the comment, $10^{-5}$ is an unrealistically useless precision.

You can still do what you want though. I am assuming a formula
$$ \{(x,y)\in \alpha\,\mathbb{Z}^2|~x^2+y^2<1\},  $$ and will use $\alpha = 0.1$.

The code is as follows:

```
α = 10^-1;
Zs = Table[z, {z, -1/α, 1/α}];
Zsquared = Tuples[Zs, 2] ;
new = Select[α*Zsquared, #[[1]]^2 + #[[2]]^2 < 1 &];
ListPlot[new, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio->1]
```

[image]

---

FYI, I try to set $\alpha = 10^{-5}$, I get the following error message:

```
General::nomem: The current computation was aborted because there was insufficient memory available to complete the computation.
```